# Цвет текста статус бара

Tags: android, view, android-themes

Есть ли  способ  поменять  цвет  текста и иконок  статус  бара?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с Android M можно установить светлую тему, но поставить цвет нельзя. Вообщем, в `res/values-v23/styles.xml`

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Перевод ответа от этого [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color)*:

---

После Android 5.0 — это невозможно. Руководство (гайдлайн) гласит:

> Иконки уведомлений должны быть совершенно белыми.

Даже если это не так, система будет рассматривать альфа канал Вашей иконки, прорисовывая ее белой.

---

**Временное решение:**

Единственный способ получить разноцветные иконки в Android 5.0, это уменьшить `targetSdkVersion` до значения `< 21`, но я думаю, что стоит следовать гайдлайнам.

Однако, если Вы все еще хотите цветные иконки, Вам стоит использовать метол [DrawableCompat.setTint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html) из новой библиотеки поддержки v4 (support library).